# Why Underscore.js's _.all() method returns true?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

When I execute below code using [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/#every), I get return true while I was expecting it to be false,

```
var res = _.all([], function (val) { return val != undefined });
console.log(res) // prints true
```

I don't understand this behaviour, as there is no value in array to match against predicate how come it is returning true.

Is this bug with underscore?

OR

Is this expected behaviour, if yes then why?

Comment: `_.all` tests that every element of the array passes some check. If there's one element in the array, that one element must pass. If there are 10, 10 must pass. If there are 0, 0 must pass, which is trivially easy.

Comment: Would you agree that “all elements match against a predicate” is equivalent to “there exists no element that doesn’t match against the predicate”? In logic, n-ary conjunction is also initialized with True and evaluates to True for an empty set of variables.

Comment: If there's no element in the array, there is no undefined element in the array either. Your condition `val != undefined` is never called.

Comment: https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L262

Comment: Thanks all, got it, so actually this is expected behaviour even if array is empty.

Comment: return `array.length && _.all()` instead if you want empty array to be false